# Node-Red access to zlib

Tags: gzip, zlib, http-compression, node-red

How can I compress a msg.payload to feed into an HTTP response node? I suspect it comes down to being able to address zlib, but since I can't use something like

```
var zlib = require("zlib")
```

I can't access it. Basically my question probably boils down to how to make zlib available to a function node.

Answer (score 2):

To add node modules to function nodes you need to include them in the settings.js file as described in [here](http://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions.html) near the end of the writing functions documentation:

Find the `functionGlobalContext` section in the settings.js (usually found in the ~/.node-red) and edit it as follows:

```
functionGlobalContext: { zlib:require('zlib') }
```

You would then access it in the function node as follow:

```
context.global.zlib
```

You will also need to ensure that the zlib node is installed using npm most likely in the ~/.node-red directory

```
npm install zlib
```

Comment: It seems installation of zlib is not needed nowadays, as [it's included in Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html). So, after changing `settings.js`, the following works fine in a Node-RED function node: `context.global.zlib.gunzip(msg.payload, function(err, buffer){
  if (!err) {
    node.send( { payload: buffer.toString() });
  } else {
    /* handle error */
  }
});
return;`